# Visualforce translation of apex code

Tags: visualforce

I have a very simple question for those who aren't as novice in visualforce as I am.

Currently I have a visualforce page that has an id associated to it by using the JavaScript code:

```
'/apex/ExampleLabel' + '?id=' + '{!ECS__RMA__c.Id}'
```

In the controller class I am getting the Id by:

```
Id xId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

Which works.  My very simple question is this:  What is the visualforce counterpart to the above apex code?  Essentially I want the visualforce code to read the page's Id. Is there a simple command to do this?

Also for future reference how do I encode more variables onto the url for a visualforce page?  I know that doing the above JavaScript code will put the ID on the page, but what if I wanted to put, say, the value of {!Example} and call it from another visualforce page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}` to read the parameter (or any parameter, really) from the page. Remember to put that in quotes if you're going to use that within javascript.

Regarding new parameters:

If you use Apex you can do `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put(<paramName>, <paramValue>);`.

If you are going to redirect using Javascript, use simple querystring syntax: `http://<theurl>?Param1=Value1&Param2=Value2...`